# Google Apps Script that will find for a certain values and if conditions are met replace it with a formula from another worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that records data from zapier(sheet1) and another worksheet where I store formulas(sheet2). I'm trying to create a Google Script that will replace the cell value in a range with a formula that I stored in the other worksheet if the value of the cell is 0.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet 2:
C3: =IF(S3="8jbgl!rbYvqWQ", "Name",IF(S3="k2!I2ywlY!_HuO", "Name", IF(S3="qm524WXgqx1y", "Name", ...)))

C4: =IF(S4="8jbgl!rbYvqWQ", "Name",IF(S4="k2!I2ywlY!_HuO", "Name", IF(S4="qm524WXgqx1y", "Name",...)))

C5: =IF(S5="8jbgl!rbYvqWQ", "Name",IF(S5="k2!I2ywlY!_HuO", "Name", IF(S5="qm524WXgqx1y", "Name",...)))

C6: =IF(S6="8jbgl!rbYvqWQ", "Name",IF(S6="k2!I2ywlY!_HuO", "Name", IF(S6="qm524WXgqx1y", "Name",...)))

.
.
.
.

**What I'm trying to achieve is:**

1. Check if a new row is added. if so,
2. Check sheet 1 column C if there are cells with a value of 0.
3. If the script finds a cell with a value of 0, replace it with the formula on sheet 2. (if sheet 1 C3 is 0, replace it with sheet 2 C3. sheet 1 C4 with sheet 2 C4, etc.)
4. loop it

Sadly, I don't even have a starting point, as I'm not experienced in either the syntax or the functions required to tell Google Sheets what I want it to do. Any ideas (or even obvious/plug-and-play solutions?) on how to achieve my goal? Thank you.

**Update:**
After googling for some time, I came across this script:

```
function replace() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange('C3:C');
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  var rg2=sh2.getRange('C3:C');
  var vA2=rg2.getFormulas();
  for (var i = 0; i < vA1.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA2.length;j++){
      if (vA1[i][0] === 0) {
        vA1[i][0] = vA2[j][0];
        i++
      }
    }
    rg1.setValues(vA1);
  }
}
```

The script replaced the 0 values on the first try but when I rerun the script again, it overwrites the 1st result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by using an `onChange` Apps Script trigger.

#### Code

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
    let colC1 = sheet1.getRange("C3:C").getValues();
    let sheet1Values = colC1.filter(String);
    let sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
    let sheet2Formulas = sheet2.getRange("C3:C").getFormulas();
    for (let i = 0; i < sheet1Values.length; i++) {
      if (sheet1Values[i][0] == 0) {
        sheet1.getRange(i + 3, 3).setValue(sheet2Formulas[i][0]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above function is an installable `onChange` trigger which essentially means that it will run whenever a change is made in the spreadsheet, more specifically, when a new row is being inserted.

Since you plan on replacing the values from one sheet only, using one `for` loop is enough.

#### Setup

Since this is an installable trigger, you will have to manually install it.

1. Go to your project's triggers page and click on the "Add trigger" button:

[image: add trigger button]

2. Afterwards, create a trigger with the following settings:

[image: trigger settings]

The trigger will run automatically whenever a new row is inserted into the spreadsheet.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Comment: Thanks. But The script is throwing an error: _Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeType' of undefined_

Comment: Ok, I see. I think I'm not supposed to run the script manually. But still, when I added a new row The script does nothing.

Comment: No, there's no need to run the script as it will run automatically. Try either refreshing the spreadsheet and later adding a new row and/or double checking with the sheet names. I have used 'Sheet 1' and 'Sheet 3' (with spaces) but make sure these are their names as well. @haben

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!